# have two columns with same column name, i want to delete one column from it

Tags: python

```
A         B      C       C
3735.14 249.81  0.02    1999
1443.42 48.27   0.02    2009
```

How to delete second 'C' column,(1999,2009)
both columns have same name.

Comment: is this a column as in pandas? as in your question its just a string with data seperated by space. its important to specify as the answer would be completely different if its a pandas data frame, or a string, or a csv etc.

Answer (score 0):

If it's the last column in the DataFrame you can just do:

```
df = df[df.columns[:-1]]
```

Or equivalently:

```
df = df.iloc[:, :-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

If its a dataframe indeed, you can apply the next method:

```
df = df.loc[:,~df.columns.duplicated()]
df
```